# Passing parameters from a view function to another through HTML rendered by view1 without URL changing?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 views functions in django:

```
def view1(request):
    dict_ex = Mod.objects.all()
    ............... (modifying and processing the dict_ex variable)
    return render(request, 'view1.html', {"dd": dict_ex})
```

Then I have these lines in view1.html:

```
{% for k, v in dd.items %}
    Name: {{ v }}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'view2' k.id %}">Choose this </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then I have my view2 that needs the modified dict_ex to get other values needed:

```
def view2(request):
    dict_ex = Mod.objects.all()
    ............... (modifying and processing the dict_ex variable)
    ....... (obtaining var1 from different operations on dict_ex)
    return render(request, 'view2.html', {"v": var1})
```

Is there any method to pass the modified dict_ex from view1 to view2 functions through view1.html?

I don't want to repeat these lines of code in view2 too

```
dict_ex = Mod.objects.all()
............... (modifying and processing the dict_ex variable)
```

Is there a way to acces the view2 function like this:

```
view2(request, dict_ex)
```

without changing the URL ?

I have these in my URL_PATTERNS:

```
path('view_one/', view1, name='view1'),
path('view_two/<int:id>', view2, name='view2'),
```

Comment: I can't understand your question, I'm afraid. What "modifications" are you talking about? If you change data, you should save it to the database, then it will be available everywhere. Otherwise if you're just concerned about repeating code, why not extract it to a function which can be called from both views?

Comment: Well, I change the data, but I don't want to save anything to the database. The reason I am looking for an option to send the changed data as a parameter to another view function is that the changes I made to that variable are pretty time consuming and I don't want every time I load a view to run the same function (if I would use functions)

Comment: Well I'm sorry but if you want to reuse some data between requests then you need to store it somewhere; either directly in the database, or in the session (if it is data that can be serialized).